# Unable to install locally built python package

Tags: python, pip

I recently noticed that I am unable to install my own `Python` packages.  I was getting an error that indicated that a package containing `Python` modules was invalid.  So, I updated my `setup.py` and removed some elements, this is what I have now:

`from setuptools import setup`

```
setup(
    name='project',
    version='0.3.0',
    packages=['project'],
    license='GPL',
    #zip_safe=False,
    #include_package_data=True,
    #package_data = { 'package': [ 'README.txt', '*.py' ] },

    install_requires=[
        'PyYAML >= 3.11',
        'logger >= 0.2.0',
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['project = project:main']
    },
)
```

I removed some elements and called the project project. Essentially, within project, I had a package, libraries, with some Python modules.  Prior to removing these lines:

```
#zip_safe=False,
        #include_package_data=True,
        #package_data = { 'package': [ 'README.txt', '*.py' ] },
```

... it was not working recently.

Oddly enough though, this `setup.py` was working as far as I could tell up until a month ago. That said, after commenting those items out and running `python setup.py` build, I no longer get the error about the package being invalid, but at the same token, I see that nothing gets installed when running `pip install dist/project-0.0.1.tar.gz`. Inside the file, built by `python setup.py sdist`, I do see all the files that I would expect to see. They just don't get installed, so I'm effectively missing all of the packages underneath the root folder (which is everything except init).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hmm, so something changed such that packages is no longer recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
The solution was:

```
packages=find_packages(),
```

The hackish solution for me was to do this:

```
packages=['project', 'project/libraries', 'project/system', 'project/services'],
```

For whatever reason, packages was no longer working recursively.

As soon as I did that, voila, it worked.  I'll probably circle back to this later as I'm curious what changed.

Comment: `packages` has never worked recursively. Either you list all packages and subpackages manually or call `find_packages()`. It always was so.

Comment: Adding to the above comment: `project/libraries` and the rest are not valid package names and can't be resolved by `distutils`.

Comment: @phd, okay, what led me to this solution was using find_packages().  What is the right way to use find_packages()?

Comment: @hoefling should it be project.libraries?  When importing, I'm doing from project.libraries import reader or something to that effect.  Should I also be using a "." in setup.py for packages?

Comment: @Walter if `project/` is in the same dir as `setup.py`, then `packages=find_packages()` will find the packages. You can test that by running `python -c "from setuptools import find_packages; print(find_packages())"` from the terminal. As for package names: yes, `project.libraries` should be the correct one, assuming `libraries` is a package itself.

Comment: @hoefling thanks - I fixed the package names as you indicated, and I'm using find_packages() now.